# TypeName in Excel VBA returns what?

Tags: vba, excel, types

I want to check what data type is in: `Cells(2, 1).Value` i.e. "WHAT GOES HERE?" below.

I tried the names (Integer / Long etc.) but doesn't seem to accept.

```
If TypeName(Cells(r, 1).Value) = "WHAT GOES HERE?"  Then
    MsgBox "Yes"

Else
    MsgBox "No"

End If
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint (F9), then run the code and when you hit the breakpoint press Ctrl+G to get to the *immediate pane*, then type `?TypeName(Cells(r,1).Value)` to get your answer.

Comment: Thank you. Although not what I am looking for, this is an extremely useful tip! Great for debugging and double checking!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well a look into [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TypeName-Function-581cb27e-4faa-45ba-a94b-5d96e43195ff?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) reveals a table of possible return values

```
String Returned     Variable
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Object type         An object whose type is objecttype
Byte                Byte value
Integer             Integer
Long                Long integer
Single              Single-precision floating-point number
Double              Double-precision floating-point number
Currency            Currency value
Decimal             Decimal value
Date                Date value
String              String
Boolean             Boolean value
Error               An error value
Empty               Uninitialized
Null                No valid data
Object              An object
Unknown             An object whose type is unknown
Nothing             Object variable that doesn't refer to an object
```

In addition you can also see the above table by using the built-in help (credit goes to Axel Richter). To quickly jump to the according page, select the function and press <kbd>F1</kbd>  or navigate to the help page via the object browser like so:

[image]

Comment: I'm giving this one the answer even though the other one answered correctly. I like it when people direct users to resources for easier questions, rather than give an exact answer. Thanks.

Comment: @J.H sure. until one day Microsoft decides to once more redesign their web docs and then that MSDN link rots and this link-only answer becomes utterly useless. Stack Overflow is supposed to be the resource.

Comment: I see the point of Mat's Mug - but of course the better option would be to have a reliable way of linking to MSDN. I updated the answer so that it immediately reflects what the referenced page is all about in case the link is broken in the future but hopefully other users coming to this question will use the MSDN link to get the current information (in case it still exists :))

Comment: @DAXaholic: You could mention further that even if the link is broken, one can put the text cursor within the function name `TypeName` in VBA-Editor and press [F1]. Then exactly the same information is displayed. And this hopefully will be so as long Excel VBA exists.

Answer (score 3):

If your cell contains a number, then the likely TypeName is "Double"

```
If TypeName(Cells(r, 1).Value) = "Double"  Then
    MsgBox "Yes"

Else
    MsgBox "No"

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick note: You can just try it out. Fill the Cell you want to check with a Value and use

```
MsgBox TypeName(cells(2, 1).Value)
```

If the cells is empty, this returns `Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number of the variable from the [MSDN Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/vartype-function), then you need `VarType`.

Like this:

| Constant | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vbEmpty | 0 | Empty (uninitialized) |
| vbNull | 1 | Null (no valid data) |
| vbInteger | 2 | Integer |
| vbLong | 3 | Long integer |
| vbSingle | 4 | Single-precision floating-point number |
| vbDouble | 5 | Double-precision floating-point number |
| vbCurrency | 6 | Currency value |
| vbDate | 7 | Date value |
| vbString | 8 | String |
| vbObject | 9 | Object |
| vbError | 10 | Error value |
| vbBoolean | 11 | Boolean value |
| vbVariant | 12 | Variant (used only with arrays of variants) |
| vbDataObject | 13 | A data access object |
| vbDecimal | 14 | Decimal value |
| vbByte | 17 | Byte value |
| vbLongLong | 20 | LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only.) |
| vbUserDefinedType | 36 | Variants that contain user-defined types |
| vbArray | 8192 | Array |

Then you can simply use:

`If VarType(TempArray) = vbObject Then`
Or
`If VarType(TempArray) = 9 Then`