# Python win32com get COM Object's TypeName or Class

Tags: python, com, pywin32

I'm currently trying to replicate some VBA code in python using win32com. This particular code uses `TypeName` and I've made a MWE with Excel (not the actual program I'm interfacing with) below:

```vb
' VBA script that will print "Worksheet" as the TypeName
Public Sub GetActiveSheet()
MsgBox TypeName(ActiveSheet)
End Sub
```

It looks like something is possible using `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch`, for example:

```py
excel_gc = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
sheet_gc = excel_gc.ActiveSheet
#> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x83075408>
type(sheet) 
#> <class 'win32com.gen_py.00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x8._Worksheet._Worksheet'>
```

Unfortunately, I have to use `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch` with this application as it appears to use a factory design pattern often returning "AnyObject". When I use dynamic.Dispatch, I no longer have information of the COMObject type:

```py
excel = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
sheet = excel.ActiveSheet  # <COMObject <unknown>>
type(sheet)
#> <class 'win32com.client.dynamic.CDispatch'>
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on how to get type information from an `<COMObject <unknown>>` object from `win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch`? Thanks!

Comment: What use is getting the `type` helpful? Is there anything in vba that the code does based on the type ?

Comment: There is a switch statement that changes the behaviour based on the object returned from the factory. For example, `ShapeFactory()` can return `Square` or `Circle` and if it's a `Square` then I want the area and if it's a `Circle` I want the perimeter. When using `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch`, the type displayed would be `<COMObject <AnyShape>>` instead of `<COMObject <Square>>`

Comment: How VB/VBA's TypeName really works has never been documented AFAIK. It's a mix of well-known VBA types (like Integer or Boolean, etc.) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365630/typename-in-excel-vba-returns-what and dynamic discovery for "other" types. Dynamic discovery is based on IProvideClassInfo/IProvideClassInfo2 interface (and maybe some other tricks) you have a delphi example here: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/2f/262023.html

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, I'll have a look through the delphi code and try to piece together a python equivalent. I'll post an answer if I get it working

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this one-liner to replicate the behavior of VBA's `TypeName`. I've tested it mostly with CATIA's COM API, but seems to work with Excel as well.

```py
def type_name(obj):
    return getattr(obj, "_oleobj_", obj).GetTypeInfo().GetDocumentation(-1)[0]
```